# can we check the size of dynamic array on runtime

Tags: c++, arrays

I create an array of size `int arr[50];` but I will insert value in it during compile time , like my solution will insert 10 values in it after performing some function (different amount of values can come) , Now in second part of my program I have to loop through the array like `it should iterate <= total values of array` like in `int arr[50]` my program save `10` values , it should iterate to it only `10` times but how I can get that there is only 10 values in that array.

```
arr[50]=sum;
for (int ut=0; ut<=arr[100].length();ut++)
```

Though i know `ut<=arr[100].length()` is wrong , but its just assumption , that function will work if I solve condition in this way.

Edit:

I know we can use vector , but I am just looking that type of thing using array.

Thanks for response

Comment: Use a vector. To avoid the overhead of resizing on `push_back`, you can call `reserve` on it first.

Comment: No, there's no way to check how many elements of the array have been initialized.

Comment: so we can only left with the option of vector ?

Comment: @Munieb The best option is a vector :D

Comment: `I know we can use vector , but I am just looking that type of thing using array.` So why the allergic reaction to using `std::vector`?

Comment: [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) can be used if you are using fixed length arrays.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie am happy with vector :) just because i am just practising that if i bound to only array then what should be the answer or what will be the way

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I don't know how much values will be added into the array when the program run , calculation may add 30, may add 40 values into array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the array you show is not a "Dynamic Array". It's created on the stack; it's an automatic variable.

For your particular example, you could do something like this:

```
int arr[50];
// ... some code
int elem_count = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

In that case, the `sizeof(arr)` part will return the total size of the array in bytes, and `sizeof(arr[0])` would return the size of a single element in bytes.

However, C-style arrays come with their share of problems. I'm not saying never use them, but keep in mind that, for example, they adjust to pointers when passed as function arguments, and the `sizeof` solution above will give you an answer other than the one you are looking for, because it would return `sizeof(int*)`.

As for **actual** dynamically allocated arrays (where all what you have is the pointer to that array), declared as follows:

```
int *arr = new int[50];
// ... do some stuff
delete [] arr;
```

then `sizeof(arr)` will also give you the size of an `int*` in bytes, which is not the size you are looking for.

So, as the comments suggested, if you are looking for a convenient random access container where you want to conveniently and cheaply keep track of the size, use a `std::vector`, or even a `std::array`.

**UPDATE**

To use a `std::array` to produce equivalent code to that in your question:

```
std::array<int, 50> arr;
```

and then use it like a normal array. Keep in mind that doing something like `arr[100]` will not do any bounds checking, but at least you can obtain the array's size with `arr.size()`.

Comment: how to use std::array in this case ? can you just give a clue ?

Comment: I am just reading it `arr.size()` will return the size of array if arr size of 50 contain only 10 element in it ? yea ?